# jsoup code works in Java but not in Android- Nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to write a weather scraping android app using jsoup. I have code working in Java, but even the simplest form I can write in android throws an error. Here's part of my code:

```
private class Retrieve_Weather extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private final String TAG = "Retrieve_Weather";

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String weatherline= "oTHErly";
        Log.i(TAG, weatherline);
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "trying document...");
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://m.wund.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?brand=mobile&query=02139").get();
            Log.i(TAG, "after document");
            weatherline = "newline";
            }
        catch (IOException except) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Cannot Connect", except);   
            except.printStackTrace();
            weatherline = "Can't Connect";
            Log.i(TAG, "End stacktrace");

        }

        Log.i(TAG, weatherline);
        return weatherline;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
    }


}
```

I've played around with my code and logcat enough to figure out that my error is a nullpointerexception thrown when I run .get(). I just can't figure out why or how to fix it. Here's my stacktrace:

```
07-09 03:18:13.901: I/Retrieve_Weather(1754): trying document...
07-09 03:18:15.900: D/dalvikvm(1754): GC_CONCURRENT freed 80K, 7% free 2711K/2912K, paused 83ms+20ms, total 244ms
07-09 03:18:15.910: D/dalvikvm(1754): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 157ms
07-09 03:18:16.351: D/dalvikvm(1754): GC_CONCURRENT freed 297K, 15% free 2841K/3340K, paused 81ms+124ms, total 329ms
07-09 03:18:16.740: W/dalvikvm(1754): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Entities;
07-09 03:18:16.740: W/dalvikvm(1754): Exception Ljava/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError; thrown while initializing Lorg/jsoup/nodes/Entities$EscapeMode;
07-09 03:18:16.810: W/System.err(1754): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-09 03:18:16.830: W/System.err(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:94)
07-09 03:18:16.830: W/System.err(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:160)
07-09 03:18:16.860: W/System.err(1754):     at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:482)
07-09 03:18:16.880: W/System.err(1754):     at com.example.weatherresponse.Weather.onCreate(Weather.java:35)
07-09 03:18:16.880: W/System.err(1754):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-09 03:18:16.911: W/System.err(1754):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-09 03:18:16.911: W/System.err(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-09 03:18:16.960: W/System.err(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-09 03:18:16.970: W/System.err(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-09 03:18:16.970: W/System.err(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-09 03:18:16.980: W/System.err(1754):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 03:18:16.990: W/System.err(1754):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 03:18:16.990: W/System.err(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-09 03:18:16.990: W/System.err(1754):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 03:18:17.010: W/System.err(1754):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 03:18:17.061: W/System.err(1754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-09 03:18:17.061: W/System.err(1754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-09 03:18:17.061: W/System.err(1754):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 03:18:17.090: W/System.err(1754): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-09 03:18:17.090: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Document.java:210)
07-09 03:18:17.150: W/dalvikvm(1754): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
07-09 03:18:17.150: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Document.java:18)
07-09 03:18:17.160: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:27)
07-09 03:18:17.160: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:40)
07-09 03:18:17.160: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:37)
07-09 03:18:17.170: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:30)
07-09 03:18:17.170: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:102)
07-09 03:18:17.170: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:498)
07-09 03:18:17.215: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:154)
07-09 03:18:17.215: W/System.err(1754):     at com.example.weatherresponse.Weather$Retrieve_Weather.doInBackground(Weather.java:85)
07-09 03:18:17.220: W/System.err(1754):     at com.example.weatherresponse.Weather$Retrieve_Weather.doInBackground(Weather.java:1)
07-09 03:18:17.220: W/System.err(1754):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-09 03:18:17.230: W/System.err(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-09 03:18:17.230: W/System.err(1754):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-09 03:18:17.240: W/System.err(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-09 03:18:17.240: W/System.err(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-09 03:18:17.240: W/System.err(1754):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-09 03:18:17.260: W/System.err(1754): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Entities.java:20)
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     ... 17 more
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.loadEntities(Entities.java:151)
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Entities.java:135)
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     ... 18 more
07-09 03:18:17.383: I/System.out(1754): ExecExceptjava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Document.java:210)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Document.java:18)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:27)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:40)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:37)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:30)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:102)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:498)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:154)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.example.weatherresponse.Weather$Retrieve_Weather.doInBackground(Weather.java:85)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.example.weatherresponse.Weather$Retrieve_Weather.doInBackground(Weather.java:1)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     ... 4 more
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Entities.java:20)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     ... 17 more
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.loadEntities(Entities.java:151)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Entities.java:135)
07-09 03:18:19.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     ... 18 more
```

My code runs correctly except for this single, basic line. I've tested my code on both an emulator and an android phone, and both had internet access. I've tried multiple websites, and the mobile versions of those websites, but none have worked. I have internet permissions in my manifests and my library files in the correct place. I've looked around a lot on this site and others for solutions to my problem. I've modified my code and permissions due to what I've found in related posts, but I have yet to find an answered post that works for me. I have, however, found a few unanswered posts that ask the exact same question. The only answer I found that I haven't tried is to this question [Error when releasing APK with AsyncTask and Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197984/error-when-releasing-apk-with-asynctask-and-jsoup): I can't figure out which file to change this in to test if it solve my issue. I'm fairly new to programming- any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code works now! I ended up moving my .jar file into lib instead of using it as a referenced external jar, as recommended in [Android-SDK r17 ruins working projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824491/android-sdk-r17-ruins-working-projects/9824539#9824539). I also added a user agent and reworked my AsyncTask so that Jsoup.connect(*url*) is in onPreExecute while leaving .get() in doInBackground.

```
    private class Retrieve_Weather extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private final String TAG = "Retrieve_Weather";
    Connection con = null;

    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        //Log.i(TAG, weatherline);
        Document doc = null;
        if (con !=null){
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "trying document...");
                doc = con.get();
                Log.i(TAG, "after document");
                Element currentWeather = doc.getElementById("curCond");
                currentweather = currentWeather.text();
                Log.i(TAG, currentWeather.text());
                }
            catch (IOException except) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Cannot Connect", except);   
                except.printStackTrace();
                currentweather = "Can't Connect";
                Log.i(TAG, "End stacktrace");

            }

        }
        else{
            currentweather = "Connection returned null";
        }

        //Log.i(TAG, weatherline);
        return currentweather;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        Log.i(TAG, "trying to connect...");
        con = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=zmw:02142.1.99999").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0");
        Log.i(TAG, "CONNECTED!!!");

        }




    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");

    }


}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add these lines to proguard-project.txt

```
-keep public enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at the source code for org.jsoup.nodes.Entties https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Entities.java

looks like its trying to load "entities-base.properties" from class path and unable to find it. Can you make sure these files are "entities-full.properties" available and in the classpath.

just a hint for future debugging always look for deepest exception, in your case

```
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.loadEntities(Entities.java:151)
07-09 03:18:17.290: W/System.err(1754):     at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Entities.java:135)
```

The last line pointed me to where to look for. hope this helps

Comment: Wouldn't that just be in the jsoup .jar file? Thanks!

Comment: This should be available in final jar file that you deploy

Comment: Both entities-full.properties and entities-base.properties are within the .jar file my program is referencing. Shouldn't this put them on the classpath? Thanks

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081763/access-resource-files-in-android ... resources are loaded differently in Android compared to full JVM, I am not sure but I suspect Jsoup might not be compatible with Android.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up solving my error while playing around with my code.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I believe this is actually an Android bug. It seems that Android caches the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, but does not invalidate the cache when reinstalling the app. As a result, the system doesn't see the new `.property` files, which causes `getResourceAsStream` to return `null`.

Solution: Reboot the device.